# Aligning text beside a material radio button

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I need to align some text to the right of a `material-radio-button` in an Angular app. Right now it is appearing like this:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
    <div class="question">
      <div class="row">
        <h5 class="app">Cerner Clairvia</h5>
      </div>
      <mat-radio-group class="radio-group row" [(ngModel)]="cernerValue">
        <mat-radio-button #cerner1 class="radio-item col-md-2" value="Charge RN" (click)="onRadioClick(8, $event, cerner1)">Charge RN</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button #cerner2 class="radio-item col-md-2" value="POE" (click)="onRadioClick(8, $event, cerner2)">POE</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button #cerner3 class="radio-item col-md-2" value="View Only" (click)="onRadioClick(8, $event, cerner3)">View Only</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button #cerner4 class="radio-item col-md-2" value="Administration" (click)="onRadioClick(8, $event, cerner4)">Administration <p class="required">(Supervisor, Manager, Director)</p></mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <input #clairviaLocation type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" id="clairviaLocation" name="clairviaLocation" placeholder="Enter location..." (keyup)="onTextChange(8, clairviaLocation.value)"/>
    </div>
```

Specifically the line

```
<mat-radio-button #cerner4 class="radio-item col-md-2" value="Administration" (click)="onRadioClick(8, $event, cerner4)">Administration <p class="required">(Supervisor, Manager, Director)</p></mat-radio-button>
```

CSS

```
.radio-group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.radio-item{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.required {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

No matter how I try to do this I can't get the red text to cleanly align to the right of "Administration".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can set the p.required as display: inline; or use <span> instead of <p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-deep to access mat-radio-label-content class which will allow you to align the content using CSS without changing the HTML structure

```css
::ng-deep.mat-radio-label .mat-radio-label-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.mat-radio-button p{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, thank you. Quick question though; I haven't been able to reuse this code to do the same with with a mat-select-list. How could I do that?
````
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-12" checkboxPosition="before" value="Provider">Provider <p class="required">(Submit separate MSOW credentialed provider build form)</p></mat-list-option>
````

Comment: ::ng-deep.mat-selection-list .mat-list-text{
  flex-direction: row !important;
}

Comment: Bless you @Mr. Stash